# I try to get information from 4 different tables of the same database

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join, where-clause

In order to create a list of data, I try to get information from 4 different tables of the same database, using php and only one sql statement. The tables are linked together as follows with foreing keys:
P and B have their primary keys as foreing keys in D. 
T has its primary key as foreing key in B

[image: Here is the data base]

It's easy with 3 diferent sql statements,

```
{
$sql1="SELECT * FROM daneismos WHERE danDateEpistr IS NULL ORDER BY danDateDaneis";

$sql2="SELECT * FROM titlos WHERE titlosId IN 
(SELECT bookTitle FROM book WHERE bookID = '".$recDaneismos['danBookId']."')";

$sql3="SELECT * FROM person WHERE personId = '".$recDaneismos['danPersonId']."'"; 
}
```

but too complicated for me using just one.

Comment: Please format your question .. see the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could help you:

```
SELECT p.X, d.Y, b.Z, t.F
FROM person p
  JOIN daneismos d ON p.personId = d.danPersonId
  JOIN book b ON d.danBookId = b.bookID
  JOIN titlos t ON t.titlosId = b.bookTitle
  WHERE b.bookId = '$danBookId'
    AND personId = 'danPersonId';
```

Even you can put where conditions on join methods.
Btw, be careful with this multi join statements because could make your database slower